# form.name.value

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am working on an app related to addresses.

I tested my function with hardcoded address like this:

```
var address = "India Gate , Rajpath, New Delhi, Delhi";
```

It is working fine.

But now when I am using that function to get adderss from user through a form and using `address=form.address.value`. Then `alert(address)` is showing right `address` (string). But function couldn't work on it (for same address as hardcoded).

Basically I'm using Google Maps API. So is there anyhting special about `form.name.value` that I should know?

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = form.address.value;
alert(address);
//var address = "India Gate , Rajpath, New Delhi, Delhi";

geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
}, function(results, status) {

    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        alert("hi");
        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        addpin(latitude, longitude);
    }
});
```

```html
<form>
    Your Name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
    Your Email:<input type="text" name="email"/><br/>
    Company name:<input type="text" name="company"/><br/>
    Street address:<input type="text" name="address"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="getlatlong(this.form)">
</form>
```

Comment: Please post the code and the HTML that do not work for you.

Comment: @madfriend basically google map api is not recognizing it as address. The given address is a famous place in our country and its working when address is hardcoded.

Comment: google geocode api returns the address. [`see here`](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=India+Gate+,+Rajpath,+New+Delhi,+Delhi&sensor=true)

Comment: The `form` variable is undefined... Try `document.forms[0].elements['name'].value`.

Comment: try  `'address': ""+address` to be sure is a string. Other thing you can try is give an id to address input `<input type="text" name="address" id="address"/>` and get the value with `getElementById()`: `document.getElementByID("address").value`

Comment: @PabloMartinez  'address': ""+address didnt work

Comment: guys but alert(address); is showing me right result (showing me India Gate , Rajpath, New Delhi, Delhi)

Comment: Firebug or javascript console throws any errors?

Answer (score 0):

`form.name` reflects to the `name` attribute of the `form` element

```
<form name="form1" />
```

---

```
console.assert(form.name == "form1");
```

You could use `form.elements.name` which will be that you want. But in this case, you cannot reach the `length` named element, because that's the `form.elements` collection's length.

Comment: In short - use IDs or some other unambiguous way of referencing elements.